# Create a FIFO table with SQlite for Android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to create a FIFO table in order to save only the most 50 recent infomations by deleting the oldest elements when a new infomation arrives. I can do it by manipulating ID in the table but I don't think it is the best solution. Any idea of doing it well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to play with IDs in order to create a FIFO logic. The best would be to add another column as `DATETIME` in your table which automatically inserts current time-stamp that will help you to select records in ascending order with respect to this column. Your new column should be something like:

```
DateAdded DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Make sure when ever you insert new record, you must do a `COUNT` check of total records in this table and if necessary delete the oldest record with respect to **DateAdded**. Moreover, you can make use of `LIMIT` and/or `MAX` in your select-query when it comes to delete the oldest record.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have adopted a similar method to optimize the code.

Comment: Please can you elaborate little more?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking for date time, sorting your items, and whatnot, you can just assume that the first row in your table is the last to be inserted.

In your Content Provider's `insert(Uri uri, ContentValues cv)`, before doing your `db.insert` call, you can first query the number of items on that table using getCount() and delete the first row if count>50. Then proceed with your insert call.

Answer (score 0):

Add a datetime type column to your table if it doesn't contain it yet and set it to 'now' on each insert. Then on each insert select all with limit set to 50 sorted by date. Choose the last item and run a delete query to delete everything older than this last item.

Answer (score 0):

is it must to use sqlite? can you use file handling? you can use simple [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) object and save it to file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for a list of transactions, and it works okay. When inserting a new entry I check if the count is above 50, if so, I just delete the very last entry:

```
 // Adding new transaction
    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        if(getTransactionsCount() > 50){
            List<Transaction> allTransactions = getAllTransactions();
            Transaction oldestTransaction = allTransactions.get(allTransactions.size()-1);
            deleteTransaction(oldestTransaction);
        }

         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(KEY_TRANSACTION_UID, transaction.getUID());
         values.put(KEY_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, transaction.getAmount());
         values.put(KEY_TRANSACTION_IS_ADD, transaction.getIsAdd());
         // Inserting Row
         db.insert(TABLE_TRANSACTIONS, null, values);

        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

And getAllTransactions() returns the list in descending order (based on the id primary key):

```
// Getting All Transactions
    public List<Transaction> getAllTransactions() {
        List<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TRANSACTION_ID + " DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                transaction.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                transaction.setUID(cursor.getString(1));
                transaction.setAmount(cursor.getString(2));
                transaction.setIsAdd(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                transactionList.add(transaction);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return transactionList;
    }
```